# How can I get facebook location from status update

Tags: facebook, geolocation

Can I access facebook location `(latitude,longitude)` from `status update` ? is there any API for that?? Please suggest me, If you know any resources about it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a different API for that. And to the best of my knowledge, there is no separate API for pulling out location details from a Status Update.

That being said, any Status Update that has a location specified will return something like this:

```
"place": {
        "id": "243114582418387", 
        "name": "Pune!!", 
        "location": {
          "latitude": 18.51759564, 
          "longitude": 73.83373153
        }
      }
```

The above sample is from one of Status Updates that I fetched using this Graph API query: `USER_ID/posts?with=location`. However, you will still get the same structure even if you were to say, query using `USER_ID/home` or `USER_ID/feed`.

All you really have to do is check if the Status Update has a **"place"** tag and if available, parse the result. The structure above has the *latitude* and *longitude* under the **"location"** tag.

I work primarily on Android, and since you haven't tagged your platform in your post I cannot help out with the actual code. But the logic, I'm sure can be used on any platform.

Comment: Is there a way to search Instagram posts using latitude and longitude without using the API

Comment: @SitzBlogz: No clue. I have never worked with the Instagram API.

Comment: I am not asking about Instagram API, I am asking about webscraping instagram posts with geo location. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033378/web-scraping-with-selenium-python-twitter-instagram

Comment: @SitzBlogz: I still have no idea how that would work. API or otherwise, I still have no experience with Instagram.