# Web Scraping with Selenium Python [Twitter + Instagram]

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to web scrape both Instagram and Twitter based on geolocation.
I can run a query search but I am having challenges in reloading the web page to to more and store the fields to data-frame.

I did find couple of examples for web scraping twitter and Instagram without API keys. But they are with respect to #tags keywords.

I am trying to scrape with respect to geo location and between old dates. so far I have come this far with writing code in python 3.X and all the latest versions of packages in anaconda.

```
'''
    Instagram - Components
    "id": "1478232643287060472", 
     "dimensions": {"height": 1080, "width": 1080}, 
     "owner": {"id": "351633262"}, 
     "thumbnail_src": "https://instagram.fdel1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/17439262_973184322815940_668652714938335232_n.jpg", 
     "is_video": false, 
     "code": "BSDvMHOgw_4", 
     "date": 1490439084, 
     "taken-at=213385402"
     "display_src": "https://instagram.fdel1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/e35/17439262_973184322815940_668652714938335232_n.jpg", 
     "caption": "Hakuna jambo zuri kama kumpa Mungu shukrani kwa kila jambo.. \ud83d\ude4f\ud83c\udffe\nIts weekend\n#lifeistooshorttobeunhappy\n#Godisgood \n#happysoul \ud83d\ude00", 
     "comments": {"count": 42}, 
     "likes": {"count": 3813}}, 
'''


import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

#geotags = pd.read_csv("geocodes.csv")
#parmalink = 
query = geocode%3A35.68501%2C139.7514%2C30km%20since:2016-03-01%20until:2016-03-02&f=tweets

twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + query
#instaURL = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/213385402/"


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(twitterURL)
content = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print (soup)
```

For Twitter Search Query I am getting syntax error

For Instagram I am not getting any error but I am not able to reload for more posts and write back to csv dataframe.

I am also trying to search with latitude and longitude search in both Twitter and Instagram.

I have a list of geo coordinates in csv I can use that input or can write a query for search.

Any way to complete the scraping with location will be appreciated.

Appreciate the help !!

Comment: Have you considered using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of selenium? I ran your query against twitter and it worked. Also, your code should receive the query as a string, the line `query = geocode%3...` should give you an error.

Comment: @Fernando Could you please help me with the ans..  I am absolutely new to this Web scraping and been too much away from programming lately..  Truly I am more confused on what and how to proceed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make it work using `requests`. Your code would look something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

query = "geocode%3A35.68501%2C139.7514%2C30km%20since:2016-03-01%20until:2016-03-02&f=tweets"

twitter = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + query

content = requests.get(twitter)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text)

print(soup)
```

Then you can use the `soup` object to parse what you need. The same thing should work for Instagram, if your query is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.. Parsing the soup to dataframe is what one.of the difficulties I m facing too..

Comment: Maybe you should spend some time reading the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to understand better how it works

Comment: Yeah been trying even before posting the question..  Wasn't getting anywhere hence posted a question..

Comment: In the code I wrote the search link for Instagram has a location number based on Facebook location number format which i am not able to find a list of other location number. Can you please help me form the query based on latitude and longitude please. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. Would have been great if I could have got some more help.